# Angular + LoopBack deployment (strange bahavior)

Tags: angular, loopbackjs, strongloop

Here is the problem: *Locally* I can build and use my angular (v4) project and use it with LoopBack 3.x normally, correctly. Everything works fine... but.. when I upload my build to a remote server, with a fixed IP, say, 10.20.30.40 angular continues to call my loopback at localhost:3000 (yes, localhost, my local machine) and not the loopback that I've installed at 10.20.30.40 .. so.. this is the behaviour:

locally everything works fine: angular + loopback

remote scenario: angular calls my localhost:3000 and not the loopback that is listening at 10.20.30.40:3000 !!! If I stop my *local* loopback, angular stops to work. I've checked the browser cache and still not working. I have no idea what is happening because there is no error message in my console of the browser or any system log.

to build my Angular project I'm using: ng build --prod --build-optimizer --environment=prod and also only ng build --prod

the loopback is working fine locally and remotely, just installed nodejs + postgresql

Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance.